# I want to be able to search in two sub-directories with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to be able to search in two sub-directories with .htaccess

I have the following directory structure

[image: dir]

My problem is:

When for example a request on

```
resources/images/players_small_pigs/BMI10.png
```

is being received, I would like to be able to search in the path

```
webapp/public/resources/images/players_small_pigs/BMI10.png
```

is the file not to find here, I would like to continue the search in

```
webapp/adminpanel/resources/images/players_small_pigs/BMI10.png
```

Can some one help me to get it to work by using the .htaccess file? The problem throughout the entire folder structure resources, views, and webservices, I think it might be a bad structure I have and maybe I should put them all in a folder, rather than having it split up between a adminpanel and public folder, what would you recommend?

I have the following code in .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(resources/.*)$ /webapp/public/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(resources/.*)$ /webapp/adminpanel/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^webservices/(.*)$ /webapp/public/webservices/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^webservices/(.*)$ /webapp/adminpanel/webservices/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(public/resources/images/)(sponsors/)?(.*)$ /webapp/$1$2$3 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} adminpanel
RewriteRule (.*) /webapp/adminpanel/views/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !adminpanel
RewriteRule (.*) /webapp/public/views/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^$ /webapp/public/views/index.php [L]
```

Comment: Why would you need to “search” for images, especially on this level (.htaccess/rewriting)? Why does your app not _know_ where the images it wants to display are located? // If you really want to implement this, then you will need to use `RewriteCond`, only that can check if a file exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the following rule a try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/resources
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/webapp/public%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/webapp/public%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/resources
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/webapp/adminpanel%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/webapp/adminpanel%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```